# php and mysql get data by year and date wise! table structure?

Tags: php, mysql, row

While making a sample details page, I just stuck upon a really confusing situation. What i actually want to do is like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
+ Year  | Month   | Date        | Total Gain +
+----------------------------------------------------+
+ 2003  | January | 26/01/2003  |  +90 %             + 
+ 2003  | January | 27/01/2003  |  +10 %             +   
+ 2003  | Feburary| 01/02/2003  |  -29 %             +
+ 2003  | Feburary| 15/02/2003  |  +0.52 %           +
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

What I actually want is that I can list the Month names and year wise like `mysql_query('SELECT month FROM mytable WHERE year="2003"');`

But the problem is it shows January two time. I want to display January one time and a link next to it which will carry to the next page. This will show the stats of January.

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what youre looking for is `DISTINCT` query, ie

```
SELECT DISTINCT year, month FROM mytable
```

Comment: YES,exactly it achives nearly , but it will only show the month name, like this query mysql_query(SELECT DISTINCT month FROM mytable) and what if i want to show month name and year name like in the table Month/Year, using this query i am only assuming the Month name but cant get the Year name as i am specifically targeting the month!

Comment: Distinct will display the same results since the date and the Total Gain are differents.

Comment: Well, you have to describe better what you want to achieve, it's not clear to me right now...

Comment: You can get an idea from here : fxmaster.net/history/smshistory.html  this describes what i actually am trying to achieve...

Comment: So do you want to get distinct year and month names? then just add year to the select list, ie `SELECT DISTINCT year, month FROM mytable`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should use a `GROUP BY` clause and calculates your Total gain as well.

(Since the table structure is not specified, I'll guess here)

```
SELECT `Year`, `Month`, SUM(gain) AS 'Total Gain +' FROM table GROUP BY month, year;
```

Comment: @Ahsan Great that you got your answer but I'm confused - was my answer right or BookOfZeus's one (which you marked as accepted now)?